# Is there a command key to editing the PR description on Github?

Tags: github

Command-keys seem to exist for most of the major Github processes, but I cannot fid one for re-entering the description-edit panel for a PR.

[image]

Comment: From the [shortcut list](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/), it doesn't look like it's possible. You could also try going to that page and pressing `?`, which will show all valid shortcut keys.

Comment: There may be undocumented features